# Move selected items from listbox1 to listbox2, problem to save to db

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a big problem. Right now I'm using two listboxes, the first one contains all users from the database. The second listbox will be able to store selected users. The idea is that im gonna create a meeting, and invite specific users who will be inserted in a table to the specific meeting.

I'm going crazy about this, I can't get it to work. Someone has a easy solution to do this? Right now I'm using two buttons to add/remove to move the items from listbox1 to listbox2.

I'm sending the code I have in the controller and view.. 
The problem is that I get this error code 
"System.NullReferenceException: 
'The object reference has not been specified to an instance of an 
object."

How to send Listbox data back to controller in a correct way, so I will be able to store it in the db?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Users", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("Users", ViewData["Users"] as 
 List<SelectListItem>, 
     new { @class = "form-control", id = "usersLb" })
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="+" 
 id="add" 
     value="+" />
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="-" 
 id="remove" 
     value="-" />
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Users", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("SelectedUsers", ViewData["SelectedUsers"] as 
     List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control", id = 
     "selectedUsersLb" 
     })
        </div>
     </div>  


------------------------------------------------------------
      <script>
      $(function () {
        $(document)
            .on("click", "#add", function () {
                $("#usersLb 
     :selected").remove().appendTo("#selectedUsersLb");
                var selected = $("usersLb :selected").text();
                $.post("SelectedUserList", "Meeting", selected);
            })
            .on("click", "#remove", function () {
                $("#selectedUsersLb 
     :selected").remove().appendTo("#usersLb");
            });
      });
      </script>

-------------------------------------------------------------------

       public class MeetingController : Controller
      {
        // GET: Meeting
        public ActionResult Meeting()
        {
            ListUsers();
            ViewData["SelectedUsers"] = new List<SelectListItem>();
            return View();
        }

        public void ListUsers()
        {
            var ctx = new OruBloggenDbContext();
            List<SelectListItem> userList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in ctx.Users)
            {
                userList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = 
  item.UserFirstname 
      + 
      " " + item.UserLastname, Value = item.UserID });
            }
            ViewData["Users"] = userList;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateMeeting(MeetingModel model)
        {
            var ctx = new OruBloggenDbContext();

            ctx.Meetings.Add(new MeetingModel
            {
                MeetingTitle = model.MeetingTitle,
                MeetingDesc = model.MeetingDesc,
                MeetingStartDate = model.MeetingStartDate,
                MeetingEndDate = model.MeetingEndDate,
                MeetingUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId()
            });

            ctx.SaveChanges();

            foreach(var item in ViewData["SelectedUsers"] as 
      List<SelectListItem>) {
                ctx.UserMeetings.Add(new UserMeetingModel
                {
                    MeetingID = ctx.Meetings.Last().MeetingID,
                    UserID = item.Value
                });
            };

            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Meeting");
        }
     }
     }
```

Comment: I assume the null reference error is occurring in you CreateMeeting function? Have you tried stepping through the code to see if your parameter 'model' is null?

Comment: The meeting is created succesfully, but its in another table, but when i try to loop through the viewbag in the CreateMeeting it crashing... it says its null :( The table where i wanna collect what user belongs to which meeting is the problem. That table will have the UserID, MeetingID, but i cant get it to work

Comment: That's because your ViewData object is empty. ViewData only persists for the request which initialized it. Your CreateMeeting function doesn't know anything about your ViewData['SelectedUsers'] object so its null. You should be using ViewModels/Models and binding to them similar to what you are doing with MeetingModel.